# Image is to pixelated as a song is to ___?

Tags: single-word-requests, music

The closest I could think of is "low quality" but that is not as specific as I'd like, it could also mean that the music is bad.

Example:

> I like this song, but you should really get the CD. This sounds _______

Comment: Please don't answer the question in the comments. Comments are for requests to clarify the post.

Comment: This is an unclear question as we do not know just what the problem with the sound is! It could contain static from radio or scratches from vinyl or compression artifactes etc.. As it stands I should be closed as 'Unlcear'..

Comment: @TaW I think the question is clear and should stand

Comment: Well, then you surely can answer my questions, yes? No, you can't because the question is totally unclear. We are supposed to __guess__ what the recording sounds like and why.. All those answers are based on just that: Guesses.

Comment: I would be interested to know where this kind of questions comes from. I guess some kind of books preparing for examinations. But I can't see that such questions help understanding language or vocabulary.

Comment: @rogermue I don't remember exactly, but I was trying to use it in conversation and couldn't find the right word. It certainly helped me understand.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

"Downsampled" is the literal equivalent for sound.  In both cases -- pixellation and downsampling -- analog reality is overly quantitized, leading to perceptible artifacts.

In the particular example sentence, though, I might say "this sounds like a bad rip."

Comment: "Undersampled" would better describe the situation imo.

Comment: For what its worth, the sound of downsampling is different and distinct to the sound of an over-compressed MP3.  Most of the problems people hear with digital music are caused by over aggressive lossy compression rather than a change of sample rate (most compression doesn't change the sample rate).

Comment: @JPhi1618. I agree totally, see 'bitcrushed' below also...

Comment: @JPhi1618 Bitcrushing refers to quantization in the amplitude. The rough equivalent for images is posterization or color reduction. Downsampling refers to quantization of the time domain, and is indeed the better equivalent to pixelation.

Comment: @JPhi1618: True, but that’s a different issue; a low-quality JPEG image exhibits other artifacts than just pixelation, too, and earlier.

Comment: Pixelated implies there isn't enough information to display the picture looking nice *at the current size* - e.g. trying to scale up an icon will look pixelated. Nitpicking, but an icon isn't "overly quantized", it's "sampled appropriately *for icon size output*". Is there any audio equivalent of an icon? There is low sample rate audio in normal use in some situations - makes me think I'd call it **telephone quality**.

Comment: Undersampling and downsampling are vastly different. An undersampled signal will have all sorts of distortion from high-frequency components folding back down as lower frequencies. A downsampled signal will just be missing the high-frequency components.

Comment: Aggressive use of modern lossy compression techniques such as MP3 cause more than just attenuation of higher frequencies, so I think the most accurate way to refer to such music would be to say that there are audible artifacts. That would be more comparable to aggressive JPG image or MP4 video compression, which causes visible artifacts. *Undersampled* would be analogous to *pixelated*. *Downsampled* is not correct here.

Comment: Shouldn't this be upsampled? Pixelated does not mean that a large image was made smaller, but that a small image was made larger.

Comment: As many have explained, although o the right track this answer is, simply, wrong.  The 100 votes here are a spectacular example of the **incredibly bad voting that is a well-known and common phenomenon on this particular SO site**.

Comment: @JoeBlow Is this really incorrect? Would you please include an evidence in your support? Not opposing you but these 100 people up-voting is making your statement a little hard to believe.

Comment: Tesselating - pixelated can also mean to civilians "deliberately 'blocky-ized'", that is to say, precisely what is done when you "hide a face" on a news show, etc (rather as one would apply a blur in the old days).  As you know, of course this has utterly no connection in any way whatsoever to "pixels" but it is what it's referred to as.  It's very likely the OP's conception of "low data rate" for images / analogously for audio includes this conception.

Comment: hi @Jony.  I appreciate your balanced and moderate question to me, but it's so very basic I (honestly - I apologize) couldn't be bothered.  A number of other audio experts above have already explained.  Profoundly bizarre voting is totally commonplace on this site.  Nobody knows why, it's ust a Thing.  Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 56):

**Lo-fi**, from **low fidelity**:

> - the production or reproduction of audio characterized by an unpolished or rough sound quality ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lo%20fi))
> - (of sound reproduction) of or giving an impression of poor quality ([Collins](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lo-fi?s=ts))

Also **lo fi** and **low-fi** ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/low-fi)).  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_fidelity):

> a type of sound recording which contains technical flaws that make the recording sound different compared with the live sound being recorded, such as distortion, hum, background noise, or limited frequency response.
>
> In digital audio, the term "lo-fi" usually refers to an audio file with a lower bit rate or sampling rate, and thus a lower sound quality.

Comment: This could be ambiguous though; these days "lo-fi" is often used to describe a desired quality in a performance or recording.

Comment: @chapka True.  This term refers to low-quality or low-quality *sounding*  music.  *Pixelated* is similarly vague; could be that the image is created with a low-megapixel camera, or that conversion to another format reduced its quality.  *Lossy* is a great word and refers more exclusively to quality loss due to data encoding.

Comment: If lo-fi is intended, then so is the 8bit pixel games surely? So they really are synonymous.

Comment: @RemarkLima that's slightly different/more limited. 8-bit sprites are to images as [chiptunes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiptune) are to audio.

Answer (score 52):

### Distorted

From [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Distortion) (emphasis mine):

> 4. (Electronics) electronics a. an undesired change in the shape of an electromagnetic wave or signal b. the result of such a change in
>      waveform, **esp a loss of clarity in radio reception or sound
>      reproduction**

Distortion can be caused by a variety of methods, one of which is [downsampling](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/288141/99654) (which is digitally analogous to pixelation). Overuse of lossy compression can also cause distortion. It covers all use cases of "bad audio" that is not related to the actual music being played.

Comment: Even though this word is used in other contexts (overdrive/clipping), it is the technically correct umbrella term. +1

Comment: Distortion in sound is nonlinear amplification, typically resulting in clipping and harmonics. Its equivalent in imaging would be overexposure and subsequent loss of contrast.

Comment: @gingordon Can you cite a source for that? Nonlinear amplification can cause distortion, but it is not the sole cause.

Comment: @MarchHo Reference: [Distortion in music -- Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_%28music%29#Theory_and_circuits) More comprehensive definitions: [The Audio Dictionary](https://books.google.be/books?id=DulVm8t88QkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=audio+dictionary&hl=en&ei=ha7KTeyADoy4sQPvwd2SAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result#v=onepage&q=distortion&f=false) and [Distortion, Electronic signals -- Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion#Electronic_signals)

Answer (score 46):

Another (slightly more technical) option is "lossy". [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression)

Comment: +1; this is perfect for compression-related quality loss.

Comment: Lossy compression algorithms are often not noticed (MP3) meaning that the term isn't exclusive in terms of perceived quality but yeah, it's step in the right direction (if not the destination :)

Comment: @LamarLatrell When used correctly, lossy compression shouldn't be that noticeable, but when it's over used, whether in a JPEG or an MP3, it can be _very_ noticeable.

Comment: Not sure why this has so many upvotes, it's technically incorrect.  Whether or not the compression used is lossy has very little to do with perceived quality.  A lossy high-res image can look nice, while a lossless low-res image will be pixelated.

Comment: They're all 'pixelated'

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Mostly because music doesn't follow that image metaphor.  Almost all music is the same "resolution" of 44.1K or 48K samples per second, so when you hear a stream or file that sounds bad its typically because of the lossy compression used.  If all images were 1280x1024, the only difference in perceived quality would then be the lossy aspect of the compression.

Comment: @JPhi1618: The analog to resolution here would be bitrate, which is frequently different for music _(and low bitrate causes poor music quality)_.  The analog to sampling rate for images would be bit-depth, which is also typically the same _(32-bit)_ for images.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, That's wrong.  Bit rate is only variable _because of_ lossy compression.  Sound files have a sample rate (resolution) and a sample size (16-bit, 8-bit, etc).  For instance, a phone call would be 8000Hz (sample rate) of 8-bit audio (sample size).  Music would be 44100Hz @ 16-bit (very common).  Since audio _has_ a bit depth of its own (sample size), the image analog would be bit depth.

Comment: Please explain your answer in your answer, do not rely on the link.

Answer (score 18):

At first I thought **garbled**, but that's more about distortion.

Low quality sound, especially music, sounds **tinny**. An example is music on a telephone; the audio has been through a low-pass filter so it doesn't sound as rich as it should.

Answer (score 12):

You may be listening to a sound that has been **bitcrushed**.  This is an effect that can make something sound like it has been produced with an 8-bit or 16-bit soundcard.  Listen to the sounds from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xv8m90_FOaY) for an example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: +1 from me and I considered this also (I know the plugins you're referring to). But to a layperson it's a step too far in jargon?

Comment: What's wrong with a 16bit soundcard?  That's plenty more depth than you need to cover the dynamic range of human hearing.  https://xiph.org/~xiphmont/demo/neil-young.html explains why higher sample rates and bit depths are unnecessary.  Sure higher bit depth is slightly better for studio use, but you can capture in 16bit and have no real problems.  8bit samples are very noticeable, though.

Answer (score 10):

## Aliased

This is the generic term, applicable to any digital medium when describing some artefacts of low resolution.

More technically, *aliasing* is the stepping between one digital sample and its neighbour. In imaging, it manifests as stepping from a pixel of one colour to the next pixel ("pixellated"); in audio, it manifests as stepping from one displacement to the next.

Source: [any good dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A%20aliasing&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: It describes an artefact, but only one artefact - not an umbrella descriptor of all of them.

Comment: but aliasing is *one* artefact (or 'cause' of an artefact). It's not a generic term.

Comment: Arguably, it is possible to have downsampled audio (i.e. pixelation) without aliasing if a low-pass filter is applied prior to the downsampling. This is [also the case in images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern#Pattern_formation)

Comment: @MarchHo, yip, aliasing only occurs if the sampled signal has frequency (temporal *and*/or spatial) components that are higher than half the sampling frequency/pixel dimension

Comment: Indeed, only very bad audio processing will introduce aliasing. What's more likely is that the high frequencies have just been lost.

Comment: @LamarLatrell, it is absolutely the generic term for "pixellated". Pixellation is one form of aliasing.

Comment: @MarchHo correct, low-pass filtering avoids aliasing, in which case an image would not be pixellated.

Comment: @Rich to quote myself: "aliasing only occurs if the sampled signal has frequency (temporal *and*/or spatial) components that are higher than half the sampling frequency/pixel dimension" - your thoughts?

Comment: It seems like you're using a different definition of pixellating than us, we're bound to get confused unless we're on the same page right? Do you have a technical reference for your use?

Comment: @LamarLatrell I don't need one, since this is not a technical discussion. We're talking very specifically about correct, but _colloquial_ use of the terminology. See my answer, where I say _In imaging, it manifests as stepping from a pixel of one colour to the next pixel ("pixellated")_. I am (and I read it that the questioner is) referring to the _stepping_, which in an audio stream, comes across as undesirable overtones: aliasing.

Comment: @Rich. My point is that for some it is more of a technical discussion and not everyone is on your particular page... You might do well to realise that.

Comment: Your technical discussion should probably be taken to a different particular page in answer to a technical question. This one's about English usage, not a signal processing discussion. //End

Comment: outstanding, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

## Overcompressed

> 1. simple past tense and past participle of [overcompress](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overcompress#English)

<sup>[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overcompressed)</sup>

Since [data compression](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/data_compression) is the actual phenomenon that causes the "audio pixelation", this is what you should refer to.

---

### Data Compression

> 3. ([computing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/computing)) Any of several techniques for reducing the number of [bits](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bit) needed to represent an item of [digital](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/digital) data, either to save [storage](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/storage) or to use less [bandwidth](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bandwidth) when transmitting it

<sup>[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/data_compression)</sup>

Comment: Note that compression is also a sound technique, so if you're talking with sound engineers, they will think you mean something very different.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem good point! Perhaps, while referring to this, say "excessive data compression" or some variant of that.

Comment: outstanding, a great answer.  Regarding DJ's point -- you know, for better or worse homonyms are totally and completely normal in English, and that includes within technical fields.   In contrast to the second half of your sentence, DJ, **ANY** sound engineer younger than say 95 years :) when asked what does "compressed" mean would instantly explain it can mean either data compression, or the old-fashioned meaning.  Note that **there is only in existence now 'compressed' audio, there is no alternative** (other than some novelty analog recording on vntage equipment).

Comment: Hi @Ben your answer is right, but your comment is wrong.  Do not say "excessive data compression". Just say "overcompressed".  Homonyms are utterly commonplace, including in technical fields.  The word "overcompressed" (as used here) is an utterly commonplace word amongst audio engineers, you hear it every two minutes.  It's like a car discussion including "horsepower".  You do not need to qualify it, in any way, as it happens to be a homonym.

Answer (score 7):

I humbly submit **[warbled](https://www.google.com/search?q=warbled+sound+-warble)**. I can't find a dictionary definition, but as the Google search shows it is definitely in use as the kind of thing you're looking for, and to me personally it refers to the kind of distortion you get on a bad GSM connection.

Comment: Not technically 'sound', but a good word for this (IMHO)

Comment: Warbled is actually a specific kind of distortion only produced by records and tapes. I wouldn't use it unless I meant that specific sound.

Comment: @Jasmine: You also get a similar kind of distortion from very low bitrate with some codecs like AAC, and to some extent MP3.  Another way to describe that is swimmy.

Comment: Swimmy/watery is different. Warbled is like the sound of an EU ambulance siren. I understand if you've never heard a warped record being played, this term might be applied to similar situations - common usage differs than technical usage.

Comment: @Jasmine Correct, common usage does not have to reflect the precise technical term. Jargon arises from common usage, and often the chosen word has multiple common meanings at the time it is abducted as jargon. Thereafter, the common meanings are _not lost_ from the original word. Unless I'm reading it wrong, the question is about conversational usage, and not asking for help writing a technical paper.

Answer (score 6):

Consider, ***crackly*** and ***muffled***

> crackly: having or making a series of short, sharp noises [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crackly)
>
> muffled: being or made softer or less loud or **clear** [Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/muffled)

Comment: Another similar word is **fuzzy**

Answer (score 5):

**Glitchy**

Pro: Unwanted artifacts of digital storage and processing of music are often called glitches and are highly analogous to pixelation in practice: usually to be avoided, but occasionally used for effect.

Pro: The meaning of glitchy is quite intuitive, even when encountered for the first time.

Con: Not really analogous to pixelation from a technical standpoint.

Comment: Your answer would be improved by a dictionary reference.

Comment: The introduction of this wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch_(music) uses the term in the context of music.

A quick search of online dictionaries shows that they define the term more generally. I might be misjudging how widespread this understanding of the word is :)

Answer (score 2):

ANSWER: Digitized
As "image is to pixalated" is an expression of an image in binary pixal (vs. point) and a song's equivalent of a binary digital representation of song is also 'digitized'

If pixelated is used as an adj. E.G.;'Man that image is totally pixelated, it looks like a bunch of blocks". In that case pixelated to image would be like distorted to song:
ANSWER: Distorted.

I believe the most commons sense iterpretation is the first answer though:
DIGITIZED

Comment: I know that many dictionaries say that "splitting up an image into pixels to make it digital" is one definition of pixelated...however, having been a professional in graphical arts for well over a decade I have never once heard the term used that way in private or professional life. It is always used to refer to the artifacts (such as through overcompression/lossiness/scaling/etc.). The question, similarly, is referencing that usage and looking for the audio equivalent. So digitizing does not work here whatsoever.

Comment: a superb answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first word I thought of was "grainy". This is often applied to pictures rather than sound, and some of the dictionaries I looked at only had the visual definition.

From the [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/grainy):

> (Of sound, especially recorded music or a voice) having a rough or gravelly quality: *the grainy sound of bootleg cassettes*

Answer (score 2):

An image becomes pixelated when the density of pixels becomes low enough for humans to see them.  An audio becomes decimated when the speed of samples become low enough for humans to hear them.

["Decimated"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_(signal_processing)) is the most semantically correct term, IMHO.  Though I've never heard an audio engineer or musician use the term.

I'd say "Down/Under-sampled is the next closest that would be used by a non-scientist. It's meaning is further away because it implies a comparison to another state.  Under what?  Where "Pixelated" and "Decimated" do not.

"Aliased" is more general, and able to refer to both pixelated and decimated.  "Low-fidelity" is much more general referring to any number of defects.

Anything to do with compression or bit-crushing are good guesses.  But they refer to reduction of precision in other dimension. Image analog to that is messing with the number colors that can be present in an image.

Comment: I wish the word under-sampled had more prominence in your answer because to me that is almost perfect.

Answer (score 2):

**Scratchy**

Per [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/scratchy), meanings 1.1 and 1.2:

- (Of a voice or sound) rough; grating:
- (Of a record) making a crackling or rough sound because of scratches on the surface:

The meaning presumably comes from the mechanical analog audio storage medium, but also carries forward to the CD (optical medium) reference given, e.g. due to scratching.

It may be less applicable for a digitally recorded file stored on another medium (e.g. a flash disk), as the distortion usually occurs during read from the moving medium's player.

Answer (score 1):

For song, the closest equivalent to pixellated is **vocoded**, or for instrumental music it would be **8-bit**.  Though both of those would be even more apparent on the CD.

Comment: "Vocoded" often has a specific meaning that is very different from what the question is about. That is, "vocoded" would most often be used to mean "processed with a [vocoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocoder)".

Comment: Agreed - but it is a close match to the word "pixellated" in terms of the effect that the process has on the input.  I'm not suggesting that it's the right answer for the OP, but it might be the right word for someone who's come here looking for an answer to the same question.

Comment: This isn't technically correct. Vocoding was originally (and still is as far as I'm aware) an analog technique. Source: I own two, and I was informed of their history via Alan Turing's biography.

Comment: @LamarLatrell Meh, really? I dpn't think vocoding is an "analog" technique. Vocoding means modulating a carrier signal in a certain way ("blah blah frequency blah blah input blah blah"), how this is achieved - with analog filter banks or DSP - is unimportant in my view. Of course, vocoders were all the craze in the 70s and 80s.

Comment: @TobiaTesan, I said 'originally' - and by that I meant to stress it *isn't an artefact of digital compression*, which in the context of this discussion is important (in my view). Digital vocoders, like those I've found in audio applications look like they are digital 'copies' of analog style encoders (band pass envelope followers modulating/amplifying a corresponding sawtooth/whatever) - i.e. an analog 'technique'. You're probably aware hey were originally devised to encode voices in a reduced parameterisation (more channels, but they had reduced temporal complexity).. heh heh, blah blah

Comment: @TobiaTesan, you might want to query DJ McMayhems comment in the 'overcompressed answer' also ?  :)

Comment: Not all analogous words need to be perfect complements. I like this answer. One could even say something like, "Ugh! Where did you get this recording? It sounds like a MIDI file."

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably say it's exhibiting encoding artifacts, or if you want it in a word - **artifactful** or **encoding-artifactful**. @HotLicks suggests **artifactuous**

You won't find that in a dictionary though...

Comment: Wouldn't that be "artifactual"?

Comment: I was just thinking of "artifacty" or "artifacted", so I'll leave this as a comment instead of a separate answer.

Comment: @HotLicks: No, because it's not that the song is an artifact, or has the nature of an artifact, it's that it _has_ artifacts. Thus an image is not pixely.

Comment: @einpoklum - So it should be "artifactous"?

Comment: Ummm... what can I say, I can't really fault that, but I like my suggestion better :-\

Answer (score 0):

I would say that "pixelated" refers to an image that is "low resolution", which could be for a variety of reasons. So comparing an image to a song using "pixelated" for the image would be looking for a property of a song (music or generically "audio") that describes its "resolution". While such a property probably exists (I am not an audio engineer or even a hobbyist), it's probably not the property the OP really means to describe.

"Low quality" works for an image, and even works well when describing "audio", but as @Shel points out, it is not specific enough to describe the music or the song because a "low quality" song would most certainly be thought to describe the song in a different way than intended.

But taken in the context of the statement in the question:

> I like this song, but you should really get the CD. This sounds (like a) "low quality" (recording).

almost works because the statement is clearly a recommendation of the quality of the song itself.

Some alternate wordings could be:

> I like this song, but you should really get the CD. The sound of this (recording) is "low quality".
>   I like this song, but you should really get the CD. This recording is "low quality".

In a different context, the simple statement "This sounds low quality", may not work:

> Oh, **this** song, I don't like it, it sounds low quality.

"Rough", "scratchy", "distorted" all work seem to work pretty well in most cases, but again, not related to "pixelated".

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking "noted" with the song divided to each individual note.

Comment: I don't believe *noted* means that; it certainly will not be understood as such.

Answer (score -1):

A distinctive series of sounds written using musical notation.

Comment: I think you've confused *pixel* with *pixelated*.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is, of course, simply

## overcompressed

or perhaps "poorly compressed"

If you have to compress a track to send to a friend, and it turns out crappy, ie if you compressed it too much, there is one - and only one - phrase you use to describe that, you say

## "we compressed it too much, sounds crap"

Occasionally the word "overcompressed" might be used.  90% of the time a simple phrase like "compressed to much" or "made too small" is used.

Comment: [This is already offered in another answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/288265/53711)

Comment: Hi Nathaniel - if so, sorry I missed it in the megaclutter. (Even though I text searched.)  Since the whole page is so nonsensical, it's probably worth repeating.  I can bear the shame of downvotes, i think  :)  Merry Xmas!

Comment: @JoeBlow +1 for the 'crap' suggestion. Have you considered discussing this particular question in Meta by creating a chat room? They'd be a good place to raise this issue. It's easy too, I myself created one today to experiment for one of my questions which was put on hold.

Answer (score -3):

If we were to copy the etymology of pixel I suppose a sound could be "sonnelated". I generally say it's either "low-fi", or just plain "f**ked up".

Comment: I wish I could downvote. Twice. I bet you can't justify the construction of "sonnellated".

Comment: @TobiaTesan, I immediately thought 'oh pooh pooh!' when I read your comment, but I'm finding it hard to do what you suggest :). I could have sworn I've read this term (or something similar) in a DSP book, but for the life of me and google I cant find reference to it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695884/basic-unit-of-sound

Comment: @LamarLatrell: I'm usually a bit of a dick on SO, but it's nothing personal, I just think this is a *terrible* answer. Let me be clearer. OP asked for a single English word. Now, "pixelated" is not a pretty word, but it *is* a word. Like *motorcade*. It's disgusting, who coined it was trying to ape "cavalcade", in which - in his/her head - "caval" meant "horse" and "cade" meant... uh, something. But it *is* an English word. Here, you made up your own, "sonnelated". That's not an English word (0 Google results), hence the first downvote, and can't be justified by construction, hence the second.

Comment: @LamarLatrell I can't find any occurrence of "sonnellated" in that SO thread :-|

Comment: @TobiaTesan. Good breakdown of your reasoning :)  Keep in mind it actually isn't my answer...  I did upvote however as I thought it must have been the word I recalled from the DSP book I mentioned (I can't find the PDF of it at the moment, it's on a backup drive from years ago). Perhaps I should have double checked. The word I'm thinking of (construction or otherwise) was very similar however. The link was just out of interest, it's likely the closest we'll find in a webpage discussing the actual *technical* reality of an answer to this question.

Comment: @TobiaTesan, see my answer below...

Answer (score -3):

Adding this answer for completeness:

***'Sampled'***

Source and SO moderated discussion here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695884/basic-unit-of-sound

However, it doesn't fit with the example sentence, as CD's are sampled themselves...

Also, 'sampled' can refer to sampling in the spatial domain, i.e. pixels themselves.

I maintain that the (+17 votes) question itself is ambiguous.

Comment: CD sample rate and bit depth is high enough quality to be completely transparent to the human auditory system, though (if done well).  See https://xiph.org/~xiphmont/demo/neil-young.html.  There's a link to a really nice video covering some basics of digital sampling, with a signal generator and oscilloscope.  (Yes, that's the same Monty behind Ogg Vorbis and so on.)  Anyway, point is, sampling well enough that there's no perceptible quality loss has been doable for a LONG time.  Audio quality problems don't come just from the fact that it was sampled.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I'm aware... I've been commenting on this myself above. I added the answer for completeness, I figured if we were getting it wrong we may as well get it wrong correctly :)

Answer (score -3):

**Downsampled** or **Bit crushed**

The difficulty when comparing the qualities of an image and a song is that they do not equate on a fundamental level. Therefore this comes down to interpretation.

A simple black and white image is a 3-dimensional signal. These three dimensions are x-position, y-position and brightness at this coordinate.

One way of representing a song, is by making an audio recording. A mono audio recording is a 2-dimensional signal. Where the dimensions are time and amplitude.

Pixelation of an image (or video) is a result of quantising the x and y position values. A piece of audio does not have these two traits, but the amplitude and time values can be quantised. Quantising the amplitude is known as **amplitude resolution reduction** or **bit depth reduction** in the digital audio domain. Quantising the the sample rate is known as **decimation** or **sample rate reduction**. Quantising of both at the same time is often referred to as **bit crushing** or **downsampling** a signal.

This video from an installation explores the analogy of video pixelation to audio bit crushing: http://tmblr.co/Z-a4pt1CeJ8B7 (most prominent after 2:30).

Comment: Welcome to ELU. *Downsampled* has already been given as the highest-voted and accepted answer. Please don't duplicate answers; it merely looks as though you're trying to cash in on someone else's good post [even if that's not the case. I doubt you did it deliberately]. You might usefully focus on *bit-crushed* though.